Why does a wrapped component re-render every time in React Native?
I have a functional component in React native (expo) that is rendering a page via the stack navigator. This page returns a simple color picker (react-native-wheel-color-picker) which is a native component, and a button which updates the state.
I've noticed that when the color picker is output directly, it doesn't re-render during state updates (good). However if I wrap it in a simple functional component, it does (bad).
Very simple example:
  import { useState } from 'react';
  import ColorPicker from 'react-native-wheel-color-picker'

  const [test, setTest] = useState<number>(0);

  const ColorPickerFn = () => {
    // This one re-renders everytime. Why?
    return (<ColorPicker />) 
  }

  return (
    <>
      <ColorPickerFn />
      <ColorPicker />
      <Button onPress={ () => { setTest(test + 1); }}>{test}</Button>
    </>
  );

Could someone explain to me what is going on?

Use the React.memo This wraps a functional component and prevents it from re-rendering unless its props change. Since ColorPickerFn doesn’t have props, it won’t re-render unless explicitly told to do so.
import React, { useState, memo } from 'react';
import ColorPicker from 'react-native-wheel-color-picker';

const ColorPickerFn = memo(() => {
    return (<ColorPicker />);
});

const MyComponent = () => {
   const [test, setTest] = useState(0);

   return (
     <>
        <ColorPickerFn />
        <ColorPicker />
        <Button onPress={() => { setTest(test + 1); }}>{test}</Button>
     </>
  );
};
export default MyComponent;


I had actually tried memo, useMemo and useCallback multiple times - but what I hadn't tried was pushing the functional declaration outside the functional scope of the original component. So simple! Thanks!
